# How do I use the headlines and bodyText defined in my Material theme?

Tags: flutter

I have a MaterialTheme setup like the below

```
     MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(ColorPalettes.BG_COLOR),
        primaryColor: Color(ColorPalettes.PRIMARY_BLUE),
        accentColor: Color(ColorPalettes.SECONDARY_ORANGE),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(color: Color(ColorPalettes.HEADING_COLOR), fontSize: 24.0),
          headline2: TextStyle(color: Color(ColorPalettes.HEADING_COLOR), fontSize: 22.0),
          headline3: TextStyle(color: Color(ColorPalettes.HEADING_COLOR), fontSize: 20.0),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Color(ColorPalettes.BODY_COLOR)),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Color(ColorPalettes.BODY_COLOR)),
          button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        )
      ),
```

But I am not clear as how to use the headlines and the body when I style text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access using theme data as following.

```
  Text(
       'Text with a background color',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
    ),
```

Comment: Ah Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use Flutter 3 and MaterialApp 3

```
Text(
   'Text with a background color',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.textLarge,
),
```

and many another TextTheme class in newest dart 3.0 and several properties in dart 2.0 deprecated.

in dart 3.0, we use :

- bodyLarge, bodyMedium, bodySmall, displayLarge, displayMedium,
  displaySmall,

And then, how to styling text like use html+css but in flutter? you can check:
https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/type-scale-tokens

you can make experiment with font,font family,font weight, etc.